# Trouble getting my Chrome extension to get data from Amazon RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-chrome-extension, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds, ip-address

I have a Chrome extension. It uses a background.js script to post and get data with a python website that talks to a Mariadb (similar to MySQL) database. It all worked well locally.

Then I moved the python to Elastic Beanstalk and the database to RDS. The AWS website and the database work fine, but the extension has a problem. The extension posts data to RDS just fine, but I get an error when I try to get data: `flask-env.ivkkarzmwt.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com93’s server IP address could not be found.`The background.js console just says `GET 500: Internal Server error`.

Here's the background.js:

```
fetch('http://flask-env.ivkhmrzmwt.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/bootstrap')
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.text();
    }).then(function (text) {
        console.log('GET response text:');
  //      console.log(text); // Print the greeting as text
    });

// Send the same request
fetch('http://flask-env.ivkhmrzmwt.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/bootstrap')
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.json(); // But parse it as JSON this time
    })
    .then(function (json) {
        console.log('GET response as JSON:');
        console.log(json); // Here’s our JSON object
        console.log ("here's the sun");
        console.log (json.greeting)
        var integer = parseInt(json.greeting, 10);
        console.log(integer + 1)
    })

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://flask-env.ivkhmrzmwt.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/bootstrap',
    data: articleData,
    success: function myFunction(data) {
    integer = data;
    var myInput = integer
    var websitelink = "http://flask-env.ivkhmrzmwt.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com" + myInput;
    window.open(websitelink, "MsgWindow", "width=400,height=500");
}
```

Comment: Look the error message again.  Why does it say ".com93"?  Because `var websitelink = "http://flask-env.ivkhmrzmwt.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com" + myInput;` should have a `/` at the end of the literal string, to form a correct, valid URL.  It needs to be `var websitelink = "http://flask-env.ivkhmrzmwt.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/" + myInput;`

Comment: I thiiiiiiink that worked? I'm still getting the error messages, but now the page is loading. I think that's ok? Not sure really. Thanks!